# Verifying the results of Deconvolution using Residual Number System

Tags: number-theory, deconvolution

I have been reading the paper [Exact Deconvolution Using Number Theoretic Transforms](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122188901289) and I think I understand it. However, I am not able to verify the example given at the end of the paper.

To summarize, given matrices `A`, `B` and `X`, representing a 2D convolution system,

$$A * X = B \tag{1}\label{1}$$

where $*$ is circular convolution defined as follows:

$$b(k,l) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a(k-i,l-j)\;x(i,j)\tag{2}\label{2}$$

(indices of $a$ are computed modulo $n$ )

Now, as per the example given in section 7:

$$
    A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
    B = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & -2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 & -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

X is calculated to be:

$$
    X = \frac {1}{19} \begin{bmatrix}
    14 & 2 & 3 \\
    22 & 14 & -17 \\
    21 & -35 & -24 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, when I substitute $X$ in LHS of $(\ref{1})$, I don't get a matrix that equals $B$.

For example $b(0,0)$ evaluates to `0.26315789473684204` instead of `1`. The expansion of $b(0,0)$ as per ($\ref{2}$) is:

```
X(0, 0): 14/19  * A(0, 0): 1     = 0.7368421052631579
X(0, 1): 2/19   * A(0, 2): -1    = -0.10526315789473684
X(0, 2): 3/19   * A(0, 1): 0     = 0.0
X(1, 0): 22/19  * A(2, 0): 0     = 0.0
X(1, 1): 14/19  * A(2, 2): 0     = 0.0
X(1, 2): -17/19 * A(2, 1): -1    = 0.8947368421052632
X(2, 0): 21/19  * A(1, 0): 0     = 0.0
X(2, 1): -35/19 * A(1, 2): 0     = -0.0
X(2, 2): -24/19 * A(1, 1): 1     = -1.263157894736842
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know. I would suggest checking all the intermediate calculations in the example in the paper to see whether you can find an arithmetical error there.

Comment: Make any progress, HRJ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I coded up the algorithm and verified it for my own examples. However, the example in the article still doesn't verify. I suspect a typo in the `A` matrix of the example.

Comment: Could be. You could always try writing the authors.